# Why are PID values have no effect on position_controllers/JointTrajectotyController?

Tags: pid, gazebo-ros-control, joint-trajectory-controller

I read on this website https://www.rosroboticslearning.com/ros-control that PID values have no effect in the case of using position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController. Is this true? If the answer is yes, can you tell me why? and if possible, please give me some resources about this. Also, does that mean that I don't have to write any PID values in the YAML configuration file for my controllers?

Comment: You seem to have two accounts: [1](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/39994/samy) and [2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/40012/samy). You can merge the accounts, please see [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: It looks like you may have accidentally created two accounts ([Samy](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/39994/samy) & [Samy](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/40012/samy)). Stack Exchange only allows an individual to actively use one account, so please follow the instructions at [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)
Moderators [can't merge accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272251) for you but may delete accounts they believe to be [sock puppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/138432).

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood what it was trying to say. The reason why P,I,D values will have no effect in case of using `position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController` is because the interface input and output are same. The controller functions only when there is need of conversion from input command type to output command type for eg you hardware accepts velocity and you are commanding position then your position commands will be translated to velocity by controller interface and during this conversion it will use P,I,D values.

Answer (score 0):

There's basically three ways you can control a joint:

1. Torque mode,
2. Position mode,
3. Speed mode.

You can pass a reference signal to any of those controllers, but then there needs to be some conversion made. If you pass a reference speed as an input to a joint that's in torque mode, what is the controller supposed to do?

It [calculates a reference error](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/noetic-devel/effort_controllers/src/joint_velocity_controller.cpp#L135) as the difference between your reference speed and the joint speed:

```
double error = command_ - joint_.getVelocity();
```

and then [generates a torque signal](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/noetic-devel/effort_controllers/src/joint_velocity_controller.cpp#L140) based on that reference error:

```
double commanded_effort = pid_controller_.computeCommand(error, period);
```

So, what happens if you pass a reference speed to a joint that's in speed mode? It just sets the joint speed to that value. There's no need to "compute" anything, you say the joint speed should be X so the joint speed is X.

If you're using a torque controller and you want X torque, the torque controller makes that torque. Again there's no need to calculate a reference error because you're wanting the joint to do what you're telling it to do. The output should be the command.

So, to your question:

> Why do PID values have no effect on position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController?

The controller type is `position_controllers`, and the thing you're trying to control is `JointTrajectory`. You're saying you want the controller to set a position value and you're going to give it a position value. There's nothing for the controller to do - it just makes the position whatever you say.